# using DOS batch file to try to retrieve list of directories ending in *.SEQ

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am trying to retrieve a list of directories only from my NAS that end in .SEQ. I am using following syntax

```
dir *.SEQ /b /ad /s searching NAS filesystem
```

If is however bringing back all subdirectories also for example. If .SEQ directory is in /dir1/dir2/dir.SEQ, it will retrieve 3 records

```
/dir1
/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir2/dir.SEQ
```

All I want retrieved is /dir1/dir2/dir.SEQ

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
mkdir dir1
mkdir dir1\dir2
mkdir dir1\dir2\dir.SEQ
dir *.SEQ /b /ad /s
```

and get back the single response

```
\dir1\dir2\dir.SEQ
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine on my local drive, but when i try on a NAs with path like below doesnt seem to work.   \\server.domain\chromeleon$\MACH00\CMDATAROOT\ARCHIVE_A$

Comment: I can confirm that this works on a local drive, but I am seeing the OPs issue when working with a NAS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need your wildcard as part of the path name parameter, instead of as a seperate parameter. Something like this:

`dir \\server.domain\chromeleon$\MACH00\CMDATAROOT\ARCHIVE_A$\*.SEQ /b /ad /s`

Testing on my NAS I receive the expected result.

If you are looking in the current directory the path name would be:

`.\*.SEQ` hence `dir .\*.SEQ /b /ad /s`